How to connect and get API from local web server on Android phone in flutter
When I use 10.0.2.2 in Android emulator it successfully connects to local web server, but not with Android phone; below is my code:
Future login(email, password) async {
      LoginResponseModel? loginResponseModel;
      Map<String, String> body = {
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
      };

      var response = await myhttp.post(
        Uri.parse(
          "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/login",  // => it's not works on android phone
        ),
        body: body,
        // headers: headers,
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          ..hideCurrentMaterialBanner()
          ..showMaterialBanner(materialBanner);
      } else {
        loginResponseModel = LoginResponseModel.fromJson(
          json.decode(response.body),
        );
        saveUser(loginResponseModel.data.token, loginResponseModel.data.name);
        // print("result:" + response.body);
      }
    }

and what I want to ask is "How to connect and get API from local web server on Android phone in flutter", I hope someone can solve this problem.

Android 9 and above do not allow http links because they are not secure
You can use the Manifest flag android:usesCleartextTraffic to true
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic
Or you can define a Network Security Config file
https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted
